# Node.js - admzip cannot compress images properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, compression, adm-zip

Since a while I'm stuck at the import function of my quiz generator application, because adm-zip cannot compress images properly.

[Here is the errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YhouW.png) that are returned for each images being uncompressed from the zip archive.

And here is the code involved in the compression of the archive, that is the component's method exportExecute() :

```
  var AdmZip = require('adm-zip')
  var zip = new AdmZip()
  var uid = this.uid
  if (this.$parent.env === 'development') {
    zip.addLocalFile(this.$root.dbLocation)
    zip.addLocalFolder('app/dist/illustration', 'app/dist/illustration')
  } else {
    zip.addLocalFile(this.$root.dbLocation, 'resources/app/dist')
    zip.addLocalFolder('resources/app/dist/illustration', 'resources/app/dist/illustration')
  }
  zip.addFile('.token', uid)
  zip.writeZip(location)
  /** confirmation dialog */
  dialog.showMessageBox({ title: 'Confirmation', message: 'La base de donnée a bien été exportée.', buttons: ['Ok'] })
```

The importExecute() method is not required here since it's properly working and the problem is the archive itself.

Also, I tried another zip compression module, but only in production it returned a pipe error, I never understood why it did that.

I'm stuck on this since a while and this is the last thing to be done in order to finish and release my app. Whoever helps me with this will be inserted in a credit.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the relation with vue.js there? Please edit your post to make its use explicit somehow, or remove the tag if this is not important for your problem.

Comment: Oh yes sure, I fixed it, vue.js has no relation with this issue.

Comment: Seems to be a recurrent issue from what I can see on the github repo. I'd suggest trying (quick test to see if it works) another library that is more actively maintained, like [node-archiver](https://github.com/archiverjs/node-archiver)

Comment: This is actually the one module that does not work on production - I will set it up again and report with the exact error message.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/s6nlI44.png here is the error


And the code used :
https://i.imgur.com/g5QJmOX.png

Comment: @DanielMedina which version of node are you using on production?

Comment: No idea, electron-packager does the job, and it's at its latest version, which is 8.7.2.